# Index Error: Selecting the max of two rows and logging it in a separate column

Tags: pandas, indexing

I'm trying to automate billing for my boss. I have to choose the highest quantity for an invoice date and client, then print that quantity in a separate column and a 0 (or blank) for the second row associated with that client. I'm trying to recreate this example:

[Billing Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcZIx.png)

I'm having trouble using Pandas to do this. I used a pivot table to get the max quantity for each client, then merged that data with the original to get a "max" column. That looks like this:

[Dataframe snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCUQ5.png)

My plan is to use indexes to essentially say "if the Qty is not equal to Max, then change the value to 0"

Here's my code, but I get the error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" :

```
    ad2[ad2['Qty'] != ad2['max']]['Qtrly Billing Count']=0
```

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Update: Tried turning off the setting that gives me the index error, but the column I want to update isn't changing. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Even when I change that setting, the column I want to change doesn't change. Still stuck

Comment: In my answer you can see the Qtrly column changes, is that what you were going for?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going for, and that's what I was having trouble with. I tried using the approach you did before, but I fudged up where 'Qtrly' went. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recreating you df:

```
ad2 = pd.DataFrame({'Qty':[33, 47],'max':[47,47], 'Qtrly':[47,47] })
    Qtrly   Qty max
0   47  33  47
1   47  47  47
```

using loc:

```
ad2.loc[ad2['Qty'] != ad2['max'], 'Qtrly']=0
```

result:

```
Qtrly   Qty max
0   0   33  47
1   47  47  47
```